# How to deal or format data and time datatype while preparing SQL query for execution?

Tags: php, sql

I have below sql query i am preparing but it give me error:
`failed to prepare sql query`

Below is some of code lines

```
$sql='UPDATE $empid SET `Status` = ? WHERE `EmpID` = ? AND `ProjectCode` = ? AND `Date` = ? AND `StartTime` = ? AND `EndTime` = ? AND `NoOfHours` = ? AND `TaskPerformed` = ? AND `ModifiedDate` = ?';

$stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );

if( $stmt ){

$stmt->bind_param( 'isssiiisi', $status, $empid, $projectcode, $date, $stime, $etime, $noofhours, $taskperformed, $modifieddate);

}else{
exit('error: failed to prepare sql query');
}
```

I am using Wampserver in windows.

Please help.

Comment: `,` is not a recognized operator in the `WHERE` clause.  Presumably, you intend `AND` or `OR`.

Comment: Thanks, i forget that ooh

Comment: what about the data and time, this thing is correct 'isssiiisi' in bind parameter

Comment: still same error is occuring

Comment: `$empid` - Is this the actual table name you're trying to update?

Comment: yes is varchar as 'CIP004'

Comment: Try using double quotes rather than single quotes when setting your `$sql` variable.

Comment: That worked previous error are removed but now query is not executing